# emgu c# object tracking moments

Tags: c#, emgucv

well iam trying to make an object tracker i produced the filtered image which is tracking the object and convert it to white i used this to get the filtered image

```
 CvInvoke.cvInRangeS(HSVimg, low, high, THImg);
```

now iam trying to get the contours and get the center point so i used this (can't test it yet)

```
 using (Image<Gray, Byte> canny = smoothedRedMask.Canny(100.0, 50.0))
        using (MemStorage stor = new MemStorage())
        {
            Contour<Point> contours = canny.FindContours(
               Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,
               Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_TREE,
               stor);

        }
```

so i have two questions what does canny method do ? 
how do i draw a shape around the tracked object then get the center point using moment or any other method ? 
u don't have to write code just give me reference to simple code that i can use

Answer (score 1):

The `Canny` function is the implementation of an edge detection algorithm  ,it  uses a multi-stage algorithm to detect a wide range of edges in images.
refer to this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector) or [this tutorial/code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93642/Canny-Edge-Detection-in-C) to understand better.

The other part of the question is a bit more tricky as drawing a shape around the tracked object will depend on the quality of the image received after applying the canny edge detection and also the geometry of the object.

So you might want to adjust values of the canny function to suit your needs.

but you can refer to these youtube video tutorials to better understand/code your object tracking logic.

[Video 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjxWpKCQqJc)
[Video 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdjoutNR2DQ).

Hoping it helps.